# Почему запрос на сервер отправляется один раз

Tags: c#, .net, сеть

Написал клиент-серверное приложение, где серверу просто отправляешь сообщения, а он их возвращает в верхнем регистре. Проблема в том, что отправка запроса и ответ приходят один раз, хотя все сделал в бесконечном цикле.

Клиент:

```
namespace TcpClientApp
{
class Program
{
    const int port = 8888;
    static string Addr = "127.0.0.1";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите сове имя: ");
        string userName = Console.ReadLine();
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream netStream = null;
        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient(Addr, port);
            netStream = client.GetStream();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write(userName + ": ");
                // Ввод сообщения
                string message = Console.ReadLine();
                // Преобразуем сообщение в массив байтов
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                // Отправка сообщения
                netStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                // Получаем ответ
                data = new byte[64];
                StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = netStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    strB.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (netStream.DataAvailable);

                message = strB.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": " + message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Сервер:

```
namespace TcpServerApp
{
class Program
{
    const int port = 8888;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server started at " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

        TcpListener listener = null;
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream netStream = null;
        try
        {
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            listener = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Запуск слушателя
            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                // Получаем входящее подключение
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                // Получаем сетевой поток для чтения и записи
                netStream = client.GetStream();

                // Читаем запрос от клиента
                byte[] data = new byte[64];
                StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = netStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    strB.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
                }
                while (netStream.DataAvailable);

                string message = strB.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                message = message.ToUpper();
                data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                netStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (netStream != null)
                netStream.Close();
            if (client != null)
                client.Close();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделано не так?

Comment: `netStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);` — это неверно. Вы должны в цикле читать данные до прихода нужного количества.

Comment: Не совсем понял в чем ошибка. У меня же данные и так читаются в цикле.

Comment: netStream.DataAvailable - не используйте это. оно не работает так, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: а так вы на сервере вычитываете буфер, отдаете ответ и *ждете нового подключения*, при этом клиент никакого нового подключения не инициирует, а пишет в тот же старый стрим.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает как нужно.

Comment: @NaughtyBrain: Дело в том, что это не гарантирует чтение всех запрошенных 64 байт данных, может прийти меньше. При этом у вас в буфере будут случайные значения на непрочитанных местах.